# What's wrong with this try_convert usage?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, case-when

I am attempting to use the new try_convert feature in mssql2012 to convert a date/time/offset string to datetimeoffset.

The string looks like: 2013-04-25T21:56:58.077-05:00

Here's the code--I know this parsing won't work, so I was expecting the result to hit the "IS NULL"  and return 'Cast Failed'. That isn't what happened--instead, I am still getting the Msg 241 date conversion error.  Any ideas?

```
case  
   when try_convert(datetimeoffset, (cast(substring(lift.PlannedLiftDateTime,1,10) + ' ' + substring(lift.PlannedLiftDateTime,12,8) + ' ' + substring(lift.PlannedLiftDateTime,20,6) as datetimeoffset))) IS NULL
    then 'Cast Failed'
   when ltrim(rtrim(lift.PlannedLiftDateTime)) = ''
    then NULL
   else
    '~' + lift.PlannedLiftDateTime + '~'
end as PlannedLiftDateTime,
```

Comment: How do you know that the error is not coming from another part of your SQL statement?

Comment: @RBarryYoung I get the same error if I try on sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/3912

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting the error because of the `CAST` statement **inside** the `try_convert` - `try_convert` won't consume all the errors you generate, it will just return `NULL` if your convert fails.

If you use `try_convert` for both attempts it will work:

`when try_convert(datetimeoffset, (try_convert(datetimeoffset, substring(@DateString,1,10) + ' ' + substring(@DateString,12,8) + ' ' + substring(@DateString,20,6)))) IS NULL`

[Working Fiddle of your code here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/3922)

Comment: at about the time you posted this, i had just removed the cast! :) Ha! Of course it tests correctly...now that we've cleared up the 'plditallo' problem! :)

Comment: Thanks everyone! sorry for the intrusion.